# Who are the first relatives whom we have to inform for any function

Tags: vedas, puranas, advaita, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

I've heard that, if we are going to start any function we have to inform our 7 relatives (boys and girls side relatives included) to get their blessing first.

Can someone tell me who are those first 7 relatives and why they are important?

If possible, can anyone throw some additional light on this topic, please?